# How to get value from position adapter RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have 2 data items where the data has different id. When i click radio button then getting id by position.

Example : I have 2 data items, the first id is 57 and the second id is 59. When I click on the first data it must get a value of 57 or when I click on the second data it must get a value of 59.

```
private String convertAddressID;
private int previousSelected = -1;
private boolean isRadioChecked;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ModelGetAddress adapterAddress = modelGetAddressList.get(position);

    convertAddressID = String.valueOf(adapterAddress.getId());
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private RadioButton radioButton;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        radioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);

        radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                previousSelected = getAdapterPosition();
                notifyItemRangeChanged(0, modelGetAddressList.size());

                Toast.makeText(getContext, convertAddressID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ModelGetAddress adapterAddress = modelGetAddressList.get(position);

```
    convertAddressID = String.valueOf(adapterAddress.getId());
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private RadioButton radioButton;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        radioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position=getAdapterPosition();
        Toast.makeText(conext, ""+modelGetAddressList.get(position).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the onClickListener in the onBindViewHolder where you always have the position. Call the findViewById in the ViewHolder class.
Try something like this my (untested) code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ((ViewHolder)holder).button.setOnClickListener(...)
}
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button button;

        ViewHolderContent(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            button= itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        }
    }
```